# Using jQuery with Other Libraries

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My home page contains:

```
<script src="js/Config/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/Config/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
```

then, a button that leads me to another page test.html that contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        getCategories();
        getnameCategories();
    });
</script>  
</head>
<body >...
```

But jQuery(document).ready(function() is not working!!
And if I made just ​​one call to a single library, either jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js or jquery-1.4.3.min.js on the home page, the code work well, but I loss the graphic effect of jquery!!!! What is the problem??

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase it a bit better please?

Comment: which other libraries are you using? noConflict is usually quite effective at returning control of the $ object to the other library...

Comment: put `alert("Test");` inside your  `jQuery(document).ready(function()});`  function and test its fire or not.

Comment: @ danwellman: I'm using jquery and jquery mobile, there are a conflict, because when I delete the call to jquery or to the jquery-mobile, the code work

Comment: Your question makes very little sense.  jQuery and jQuery mobile MUST be on the same page as your jQuery.noConflict script... "If You delete "or from the home page"... can you rephrase that sentence please? Difficult to understand.

Comment: Please post more code...

Comment: @ Shree Khanal: I put alert("Test"); but nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `jQuery(document).ready(function()` won't fire coz when jquery mobile load external pages it looks for  the first page of your document and it don't load the associate scripts specified in the head section.

what you have to do is to load all your java script in your first html page and also put you code in `$("#test").live("pageshow",function(){}` where test is the id of the first page located in test.html

it should look like this in your .js:

```
$("#test").live("pageshow",function(){
    jQuery.noConflict();
    getCategories();
    getnameCategories();

}
```

and like this in test.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test" data-role="page"> 

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your new page `test.html` should also contain a reference to the jquery-mobile library.

Also, when using jQuery Mobile, use `pageInit` rather than jQuery's `ready(...)` function. See the documentation [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to check the dependent Jquery libraries of "**jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js**" and need to call that dependent jquery libraries links to your page.
i mean you should call the libraries like,

```
<script src="js/Config/jquery.mobile.themeswitcher.js"></script>
<script src="js/Config/jqm-docs.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have added this two lines, jQuery(document).ready(function() but the graphic is lost